# Why image in Listview is set double times?

Tags: android, listview

[Screenshot of Listview link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic8Jt.png)
I was making a menu display, and wanted to set images into my listview. However, images are set double times. I do not  know why? 
My getView function in MenuAdapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_lists, null);
        holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.music_txt);
        holder.imageView=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.music_icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);


    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

This is layout.xml for my listview:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:background="#aaef79"
        android:id="@+id/music">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/music_icon"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Music"
            android:id="@+id/music_txt"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you set `android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` in XML and set `setImageResource` in adapter

remove `android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher` in XML or change it to `android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher`

actually each ImageView can take both `background` and `src` in xml.
`setImageResource` means that you programmatically set `src` for your view and `setBackgroundResource` means that you programmatically set `background` for your view